# Parsing data with multiple delimitters using Pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I am new to Pig. What would be the efficient way for parsing data like this? I am looking at picking each field value after `=` operator like date, time, devname, etc.

```
Jun 24 05:25:01 23.45.56.222 date=2014-06-24 time=05:04:43 devname=XX-FGT-Primary 
device_id=FG3K8A3408600390 log_id=0021000002 type=traffic subtype=allowed pri=notice 
vd=XX-Internet src=23.83.57.99 src_port=7569 src_int="amc-sw1/2" dst=23.91.19.16 
dst_port=343 dst_int="amc-sw1/1" SN=116445695565 status=accept policyid=2272 
dst_country="India" src_country="India" dir_disp=org tran_disp=noop service=HTTPS 
proto=6 duration=122 sent=124 rcvd=84 sent_pkt=3 rcvd_pkt=2
```

Any code snippets would really help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for UDF called `REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL`.

And for code snippet, look [here](http://software.danielwatrous.com/analyze-tomcat-logs-using-pig-hadoop/).

Comment: Thanks a lot Mikko Kupsu